# decoration nodes not being placed on the circle they are intended to be on

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, decorations

I "placed" some nodes on a circular path but they aren't showing up in the correct place and they aren't even on the circle.

What is going wrong?

[image]

```
\begin{document}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings, calc, fadings,  decorations.pathreplacing, patterns,decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45]
     \filldraw[blue, opacity = .3] (0,0) circle (2cm);
     \draw[dashed] (-4,0) -- (5,0);
     \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}},
       mark = at position 0.75 with {\arrow{>}},
       mark = at position 0.2 with {\node[draw, circle, inner sep = .05cm, fill = white
       , scale = .75] {1};}, }]
       \draw[postaction = decorate] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
       \filldraw[black] (2.5,0) circle (.05cm);
       \node[scale = .75] at (2.7,.2) {$A$};
     \end{scope}
     \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}},
       mark = at position 0.75 with {\arrow{>}},
       mark = at position 0.2 with {\node[draw, circle, fill = white, inner sep = .05cm, scale = .75]
       {2};},
       mark = at position 0.35 with {\filldraw[black] circle (.05cm);}, } ]
       \draw[postaction = decorate] (0,0) circle (3.75cm);
     \end{scope}
       \filldraw[black] (3.75,0) circle (.05cm);
       \node[scale = .75] at (3.95,.2) {$B$};
       \filldraw[black] (-3.75,0) circle (.05cm);
       \node[scale = .75] at (-3.95,.2) {$C$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using the `mark` option several times, positions should be given in *ascending* order:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings, calc, fadings,  decorations.pathreplacing, patterns,decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45]
     \filldraw[blue, opacity = .3] (0,0) circle (2cm);
     \draw[dashed] (-4,0) -- (5,0);
     \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings, 
       mark = at position 0.2 with {\node[draw, circle, inner sep = .05cm, fill = white,   scale = .75] {1};},
       mark = at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}},
       mark = at position 0.75 with {\arrow{>}}
      }]
       \draw[postaction = decorate] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
       \filldraw[black] (2.5,0) circle (.05cm);
       \node[scale = .75] at (2.7,.2) {$A$};
     \end{scope}
     \begin{scope}[decoration = {markings, 
       mark = at position 0.2 with {\node[draw, circle, fill = white, inner sep = .05cm, scale = .75] {2};},
       mark = at position 0.25 with {\arrow{>}},
       mark = at position 0.35 with {\filldraw[black] circle (.05cm);}, 
       mark = at position 0.75 with {\arrow{>}}
       }]
       \draw[postaction = decorate] (0,0) circle (3.75cm);
     \end{scope}
       \filldraw[black] (3.75,0) circle (.05cm);
       \node[scale = .75] at (3.95,.2) {$B$};
       \filldraw[black] (-3.75,0) circle (.05cm);
       \node[scale = .75] at (-3.95,.2) {$C$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Quoting directly from Section **30.5 Arbitrary Markings** (page 328) of the `pgfmanual`:

> It is possible to give the mark option several times, which causes
>   several markings to be applied. In this case, however, it is necessary
>   that the positions on the path are in increasing order. That is, it is
>   not allowed (and will result in chaos) to have a marking that lies
>   earlier on the path to follow a marking that is later on the path.

Comment: so that is the issue only issue then?

Comment: @dustin yes; that was the problem.